# uwsgi nginx django ubuntu 14.04 virtualenv

Tags: django, nginx, virtualenv, uwsgi

I am trying to run my simple django project on uwsgi and nginx, I use ubuntu 14.04 server.

I have followed the uWSGI doc,since [here](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html#test-your-django-project) it works ok,but when it comes to [this part](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html#nginx-and-uwsgi-and-test-py) it won't work for me ,I do not know why?here is the mysite_nginx.conf:

```
# mysite_nginx.conf

# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
upstream django {
    #server unix:///home/ubuntu/d18/mysite/mysite.sock; # for a file socket
    server 127.0.0.1:8001; # for a web port socket (we'll use this first)
}

# configuration of the server
server {
    # the port your site will be served on
    listen      8000;
    # the domain name it will serve for
    server_name 123.123.123.123; # this just my example IP address or FQDN
    charset     utf-8;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

    # Django media
    location /media  {
        alias /path/to/your/mysite/media;  # your Django project's media files - amend as required
    }

    location /static {
        alias /path/to/your/mysite/static; # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    }

    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /home/ubuntu/d18/mysite/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
    }
}
```

I did not do the "python manage.py collectstatic", because I thought I just wanna see the sample mysite run on the nginx and uwsgi, however it just not work. Can someone tell me why?

Comment: When you said "didn't work", what have you done? what did you see?  btw, when you doing the test, you have `uwsgi ... 8001` running all the time right?

Comment: If you run "/usr/sbin/nginx -t -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf" it will confirm the configuration you've running. Also, are you seeing any errors? Check the nginx error log, it would tell you if it's having issues connecting upstream.

Comment: when I try MyIpAddress:8000 it shows nothing in browser, when I try MyIpAddress:8001 also is noting in browser, but "invalid request block size: 21573 (max 4096)...skip" in terminal ,,,when I #cat /var/log/nginx/error.log  it has noting inside ,,I have tried "/usr/sbin/nginx -t -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf"  thanks for your reply

Comment: I have tried "/usr/sbin/nginx -t -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf"  but it still can not work

Comment: What's in your uwsgi.log and nginx access log? What http status code do you get?

Comment: when I #cat /var/log/nginx/error.log ,,it has noting inside,when I run $uwsgi --socket :8001 --wsgi-file test.py ,the terminal just show"*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (and the only) (pid: 29192, cores: 1)",when I browser 123.123.123.123 it shows nothing,,my project is in the virtualenv,,I do not know does it has any affect?

Comment: Root of you problem is: you're not getting a response on http://<host>:8000/ (nginx). uWSGI and django are not even involved at this point. Even if you didn't run uWSGI or didn't have a django site, you should get some error template from nginx. How many NICs does your machine have, and is the one you're binding also the one where your browser would connect?

Comment: I think it is about the virtualenv,when I do like [this](http://niceoh1040.blogspot.tw/search/label/uwsgi)  ,it is ok I can see my django project "it worked" while I browsering 123.123.123.123 ,,,but when I try to set that in virtualenv,,it just can not work

Comment: when I set the django mysite not in virtualenv follow my old [way](http://niceoh1040.blogspot.tw/search/label/uwsgi),it can work ,but in virtualenv follow the uwsgi doc,it can not work

Comment: @JoeLin, how did you solve this? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: I did not solve it yet ,,,I still do not know how to set the nginx within virtualenv